# Livereload for css files sometimes dont works in gulp

Tags: gulp, livereload

I have a small list of `.scss` that will converted to css by gulp-sass. **Converting process works very fast** in less than 5ms.

But reloading css files using `gulp-connect` plugin takes a time about `3s` and even sometimes dont works at all and i have to save `.scss` file again see result in browser. Tested with/without `Livereload` extension for chrome.

**Why?**

My Sass task:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src(['source/sass/*.scss'])
    .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'expanded'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('source/assets/css'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

My watch task:

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch(['source/sass/**/*.scss'], ['sass']);
});
```

My Connect task:

```
gulp.task('connectDev', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: 'source',
    port: 8001,
    livereload: true
  });
});
```

And default task:

```
gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'connectDev', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what happend but by adding `.on( 'error', gutil.log )` after reload() and sass() problem solved.

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src(['source/sass/*.scss'])
    .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'expanded'
    })).on( 'error', gutil.log )
    .pipe(gulp.dest('source/assets/css'))
    .pipe(connect.reload()).on( 'error', gutil.log );
});
```

Maybe it causes triggering reload somehow.

Also separating `.pipe(connect.reload())` caused lag and fail. like this:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src(['source/sass/*.scss'])
    .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'expanded'
    })).on( 'error', gutil.log )
    .pipe(gulp.dest('source/assets/css'))
    .pipe(connect.reload()).on( 'error', gutil.log );
});

gulp.src('source/assets/**/*.css')
.pipe(connect.reload()).on( 'error', gutil.log );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [simple and **tested** livereload solution](https://github.com/dmitriz/gulp-automation) based on `connect` server and `connect-livereload` and `gulp-livereload` plugins that work very fast for me:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('connect');
var connectLivereload = require('connect-livereload');
var opn = require('opn');
var gulpLivereload = require('gulp-livereload');

var config = {
    rootDir: __dirname,
    servingPort: 8080,

    // the files you want to watch for changes for live reload
    filesToWatch: ['*.{html,css,js}', '!Gulpfile.js', '!karma.conf.js', '!protractor.conf.js']
}

// The default task - called when you run `gulp` from CLI
gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'serve']);

gulp.task('watch', ['connect'], function () {
  gulpLivereload.listen();
  gulp.watch(config.filesToWatch, function(file) {
    gulp.src(file.path)
      .pipe(gulpLivereload());
  });
});

gulp.task('serve', ['connect'], function () {
  return opn('http://localhost:' + config.servingPort);
});

gulp.task('connect', function(){
  return connect()
    .use(connectLivereload())
    .use(connect.static(config.rootDir))
    .listen(config.servingPort);
});
```